# Is using Cognito sufficient to secure all my endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-cognito

I am trying to develop a web app with React as a frontend and Spring Boot as my backend. Since I am new to backend development I am unsure on how to implement my security. If I use AWS Cognito, does it automatically secure all my endpoints or do I have to do further implementation on the backend part?

Comment: We need to know more about your approach here. Are you directly planning to connect to aws services from your front end after authenticating with cognito? Or are you going to connect to services with backend?

Comment: I want to connect to the services with backend. My idea is as follows: I want the user to do the login in the frontend to receive the token by Cognito and then do further backend calls with the received token. Is my approach actually doable?

Comment: It is doable. Tokens expire after an hour so you'll need to update them every hour and give the backend these updated tokens. You will have to make sure these tokens remain secure.

Comment: Is this approach sufficient to secure all my endpoints or do I still have to add some security features in my backend?

Comment: You'll have to secure transport of these tokens to your backend from your front end. Use https and it should be fine.